# Can a complete surface with constant negative Gaussian curvature be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

[Hilbert's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29) says that a complete surface with constant negative Gaussian curvature can't be isometrically embedded (or even immersed) into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can it be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$? If I understand correctly, then the [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) guarantees that it can be smoothly, but not necessarily isometrically, embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$, while the [Nash embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) guarantees that it can be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some natural number $n$ but does not give its value.

Comment: The pseudosphere *is* embedded in $\Bbb R^3$. Hilbert's Theorem says there's no *complete* surface of constant negative curvature in $\Bbb R^3$. So your question is really about isometric embedding as a *complete* surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fair point - edited to clarify.